# How does one get the model of the GPU in python and save it as a string?

Tags: python, gpu

I was trying to get a simple concise way to get the model/name of the GPU I am using in python and saving it as a string. I tried `nvidia-smi` but that gives a giant string and I don't need something that complicated. Is there a simple way that returns something simple like:

`gpu_mdl = get_mdl() # 'V100 16Gigs'`

for instance?

The saving as a file can be easily done with:

```
            with open(path / 'gpu_model.json', 'w+') as f:
                json.dump({'gpu_mdl': str(get_mdl()) }, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: `nvidia-smi` has several options to format and filter its output (see `man nvidia-smi`). `-q -x` results in a large XML, which has a defined structure and thus is easy to parse. `-L` prints one line per GPU and also has an easy format to parse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nvidia-smi -L` to get a list with one line per GPU in the following format:

> GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti (UUID: GPU-159d5c28-e2e7-c8ed-c153-72879c7a6e84)

You can then extract the relevant information ("Geforce GTX 1660 Ti") by splitting at the first `:` and the first `(`.

```py
import subprocess


def get_mdl():
    line_as_bytes = subprocess.check_output("nvidia-smi -L", shell=True)
    line = line_as_bytes.decode("ascii")
    _, line = line.split(":", 1)
    line, _ = line.split("(")
    return line.strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pytorch to get the device name:

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.get_device_name()
'NVIDIA A10'
```

In case you want to have more details on the device properties:

```
>>> torch.cuda.get_device_properties(torch.cuda.device(0))
_CudaDeviceProperties(name='NVIDIA A10', major=8, minor=6, total_memory=22731MB, multi_processor_count=72)
```